# Only want the function to work when the screen size is a certain width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this landing page that has a left navigation when it the screen with 1024 or larger but when the screen goes below 1024 the left navigation appears on the top of the main content of the page and the "Walmart Leverage becomes a button with on click event for the rest of the navigation to come down. the code works until I put the if statement to detect what size the screen is. Probably missing something to the code. Below is the link for the page.

http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2399619/walmartmilitary/talentbrew-LeverageHome.html

This is the code for the jQuery

```
$(window).resize(function() {
if( $(this).width() < 1024) {       

var $showSubBtn = $("#sn-walmartleverage");

    $showSubBtn.click(function(){

            if($(this).hasClass("active")) {            
                $(this).parent().next().hide();
                $(this).removeClass("active");

            } else {            
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $(this).parent().next().show();         
            }           
            return false;           
        });         
    }   
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can't put the click event handler inside the window resize event handler, you should just check the window size when the click happens

```
$("#sn-walmartleverage").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(window).width() > 1024) {
        $(this).toggleClass('active').parent().next().toggle();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. this only partially worked. the toggle function does work on size below 1024, but now I need to get so that click function not longer is working on Walmart Leverage and this links out.

Comment: Not sure what that means ?